# Can't access resourcePath property from webpack loader

Tags: webpack

I'm writing a custom webpack loader that needs to know the path to the file it's currently modifying, and reading the [loader documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#resourcepath), I find that the property is "resourcePath", but when I check out the context inside the loader, all the properties I have are:

```
{ data: undefined,
  inputValue: undefined,
  query: '?mykey=value',
  async: [Function: async],
  callback: [Function],
  cacheable: true }
```

My webpack config file looks something like this:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: '../plugins/myloaderloader.js?mykey=value'
    }
  ]
}
```

And the loader itself is just a normal exported function that accepts a string as per the loader documentation. Am I missing something or could this be a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, **resourcePath** is available. If you do `console.log(this.resourcePath)` you'll see the full path to your source. But if you do `console.log(this)`, the output will be as you wrote in your question. I think this is because of `toString()` method of `this` object and yes, this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still meet the same problem, take care, use:

your-loader.js

```js
module.exports = function(source) {
  //...
}
```

instead of

```
module.exports = (source) => {
  //...
}
```